# Good framework for iphone app user interface testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, testing, user-interface

I am looking for tools that I can attach to the app that would allow me to test the user interface. I was thinking about something like a click map to see where users are touching in the application, or any other visual tools that help improving the  touch and feel of the app. I am not referring to analytics like Flurry or Localytics. I am looking for something more like [crazyegg.com](http://crazyegg.com) but for iphone apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps) in my apps. It lets you test where people touch in you application, which buttons are used more then other. It's pretty good about showing you what gestures users make on your application screen, like if they are trying to scroll down.
You would be surprised how people use your interface. I know I was shocked the first time I found that people don't see the help button that I spend hours to implement with help snippets. Oh well, people are different :-)